# Как отключить процесс на VPS после использования nohup?

Tags: node.js, консоль, vps, ubuntu

как отключить процесс на VPS после использования

```
nohup node index.js &
```

Comment: @Zow: Какой у Вас дистрибутив используется на VPS?

Запуск с использованием `nohup` (`screen`, `dtach`) это костыль-времянка, а не нормальный подход к запуску демонов.

Edit: нашел-заметил и перекатился в [другой Ваш вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/141042/), который ближе к теме.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сохраните pid в переменную или файл. Потом убейте.

Добраться до pid можно так (обращайтесь сразу после вызова nohup):

$$ - pid **nohup**

$! - pid **node index.js**

Убить процесс по pid - **man kill**

Comment: а без pid можно ?

Comment: Ну можно написать оболочку, которая будет в фоне запускать index.js, а потом убивать когда вам надо. Но все равно это будет завязано на pid

Comment: @gridsane, а если не сразу обратится, то как теперь найти pid?

Comment: Получите pid процессов по имени с аргументами

    ps -eo pid,args | grep "ИМЯ ПРОЦЕССА С АРГУМЕНТАМИ" | grep -v grep | cut -f2 -d" "